# Android SDK Tools rev21 and ACRA

Tags: android

I updated Android SDK Tools to rev21 and Android SDK Platform-tools to rev16. Now my this code id not working.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate()
{
    ACRA.init(this);
    ErrorReporter.getInstance().setReportSender(new LocalReportSender(getApplicationContext())));
    super.onCreate();
}
```

ERROR:

```
12-27 10:39:37.100: E/AndroidRuntime(5608): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.acra.ACRA
```

What is going wrong ? I did check External jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ACRA jar in the `libs/` directory of your project. This will guarantee that it is compiled inside the app (classes.dex).

Comment: As I have opened my old project in the new environment I don't have libs folder. Should I create one ?

Comment: Yes, this is now the recommended way to add dependent libraries. And is much easier to use (for relatively simple projects at least)

Comment: So you actually have two questions then. Consider accepting one of the answers, so that this question goes off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` because your ACRA jar file is not available at runtime.

In order for it to be available at runtime you'll have to check the checkboxes on your jar file in your java build path like so:

[image]

Comment: I tried that.  Now it's showing getInstance() as deprecated in this code. "ErrorReporter.getInstance().setReportSender(new LocalReportSender(getApplicationContext()"

Comment: http://acra.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/4.3.0b2/org/acra/ErrorReporter.html#getInstance(); you'll have to use `ACRA.getErrorReporter()` instead.